# Creating a Quiz in Python - error

Tags: python

As a novice to Python myself, I encountered an error when trying to develop a Quiz program. I found that when the program generates two random numbers to add together, and the user attempts to enter in the correct values for the question, the program trips up and still prints that the input from the user is invalid.

```
def quiz():
    print("The quiz will begin shortly")
    print(numberone)
    print("+")
    print(numbertwo)
    answerone=input("Answer:")
    if answerone==(numberone + numbertwo):
        print("Correct")
        score+1
        print("You're score is", score, ".")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
        print(numberone+numbertwo)
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong, so any help would be much appreciated.

(NOTE: 'numberone' and numbertwo' are both defined)

Comment: can you make sure that your indentation is proper? i can only assume that everything under quiz is supposed to be indented but that makes me wonder where you define `numberone` and `numbertwo`

Comment: I wrote as a note that they are defined at the foot of the post

Comment: It looks like `numberone` and `numbertwo` are not in scope of the function `quiz`...

Comment: `numberone` and `numbertwo` should be passed as parameter.

Comment: Yes, you've *said* that, but you haven't *shown* it. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that input from your user is a string.  You will need to convert it to an integer before you can compare it.

```
int(answerone)
```

so try this:

```
def quiz():
    print("The quiz will begin shortly")
    print(numberone)
    print("+")
    print(numbertwo)
    answerone=input("Answer:")
    if int(answerone)==(numberone + numbertwo):
        print("Correct")
        score += 1
        print("You're score is {}.".format(str(score)))
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
        print(numberone+numbertwo)
```

Comment: Wow. This really helped. Thank you very much for your help :). Will approve in 4 minutes.

Comment: No worries, glad it worked out for you!

Comment: Run the code first, before post as an answer. `score+1` doesn't help you.

Comment: Yup, but the problem wasn't with score.  I will edit to fix this, but it is still outside the scope of the original question.

Comment: Indubitably, 'score+1' is a separate problem I will indeed try to figure out now. At the moment it is coming up with an error that 'TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly'.

Comment: Didn't see Martin's last comment.

Comment: ok, i'll edit again for you.

Comment: That should work for you now.

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need to define `numberone` and `numbertwo` in the function `quiz`:

```
def quiz():
    numberone = 6
    numbertwo = 3   # etc.
```

Or, pass them as parameters:

```
def quiz(numberone, numbertwo):
    print numberone   #etc
```

Comment: Same is for `score`, i found no `score` defined. Even if score is defined,  `score+1` doesn't work

Comment: What is the error? Please **revise** your original question to include the additional details.

Comment: There may also be some type mismatch going on, but, without seeing where all of your vars are defined, it's really hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign **score** while incrementing

is:

```
    print("Correct")
    score+1
    print("You're score is", score, ".")
```

should be:

```
    print("Correct")
    score += 1
    print("You're score is", score, ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of problems in your code. Let's see one by one.

- Your indentation is all wrong. You should first fix it.
- `numberone`, `numbertwo` and `score` can't be accessed under this scope. One good idea is to pass them as function parameter.

Like this:

```
def quiz(numberone,numbertwo,score):
```

- As `answerone` should be an integer, cast the input as `int`

Like this:

```
answerone=int(input("Answer:")) #if using python3
```

- You are adding `1` with `score`, but aren't assigning it back.

Use `score=score+1` or `score+=1` rather `score+1`

- Return `score` from the function to use the updated value of `score` for next call.

So, the working code can be like this:

```
def quiz(numberone,numbertwo,score):
    print("The quiz will begin shortly")
    print(numberone)
    print("+")
    print(numbertwo)
    answerone=int(input("Answer:"))
    if answerone==(numberone + numbertwo):
        print("Correct")
        score += 1
        print("You're score is", score, ".")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
        print(numberone+numbertwo)
    return score
```

You can call it like below:

```
score=0
while(score<10):
    score=quiz(someRandNumber,anotherRandNumber,score)
else:
    print "Your score is 10"
```